# What is happening in SendAsync () in.NET3.5

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, smtpclient

So in my program I'm building and sending out an email using the STMPClient in .NET 3.5. Due to circumstances outside my control I must use .NET 3.5. I'm choosing the send the emails out using SendAysnc(). Such as

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(emailsrvr, emailport);
smtpclient.Credentials = //Credentials from server
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

/*
 Skipping lines
*/
Object x;
smtpClient.SendAsync(email, x);
```

The method calls for a MailMessage and an object. In the MSDN documentation example, they use a string variable. In my code, I tried using an CallBack function that writes down the email as sent in a log as the object, but that's not an object. When I give it anything else, such as a string or integer variable, I'm sending emails with no problems.

I'm trying to see the use of the object and get a better grasp of what's happening.

Comment: Please show what you meant by "I try using an AsyncCallBack" it is not exactly clear what you tried.

Comment: In another project I worked on, I sent HTTP request asynchronously using the WebRequest.BeginGetResponse that asked for an AsyncCallback function that I used to process the results of the GetResponse.

Comment: Have you read the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx) on this? It explains it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In another project I worked on, I sent HTTP request asynchronously using the WebRequest.BeginGetResponse that asked for an AsyncCallback function that I used to process the results of the GetResponse.

That's `WebRequest`, that uses "[Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx)" (using `XxxBegin(` and passing in a callback or calling the `XxxEnd(` method). SmtpClient uses the "[Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969(v=vs.110).aspx)" (run a method that returns immediately and wait for a event to fire).

What that 2nd parameter in `SendAsync` is for is so you can tell which method raised the event, all that is done with it is passed to the event handler. If you are not using the same method for multiple event handlers you can just pass `null` directly in to it, no need to declare a variable.

Here is a example where it would be useful

```
void Example()
{
    SmtpClient client1 = new SmtpClient(emailsrvr, emailport);
    client1.SendCompleted += OnSendCompleted;
    SmtpClient client2 = new SmtpClient(emailsrvr, emailport);
    client2.SendCompleted += OnSendCompleted;

    MailMessage message1 = //...
    MailMessage message2 = //...
    client1.SendAsync(message1, "1");
    client2.SendAsync(message2, "2");
}

void OnSendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Message {0} sent!", args.UserState);
}

//Prints out:
//Message 1 sent!
//Message 2 sent!
```

For your code, because you don't subscribe to `SendCompleted` you can just pass null.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(emailsrvr, emailport);
smtpclient.Credentials = //Credentials from server
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();

/*
 Skipping lines
*/
smtpClient.SendAsync(email, null);
```

Comment: So when the SendAsync is completed, that object is passed to the event handler to be processed. For example, If I wanted to create a log of all the emails sent. I would need to define an event handler for SendAsync.

Comment: If you want to be notified that the send is completed, yes, you need a event handler. That event handler may or may not need `UserState` passed in, it is up to you, I normally don't but it is nice to have if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the links to some documentation and the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx

> userToken: A user-defined object that is passed to the method invoked when the asynchronous operation completes

You don't have to use that argument at all. You can pass `null`. Not sure what to recommend without more context.